# Resolve Error default site does not exist after update to Ubuntu 13.10 and apache 2.4

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, lamp, ubuntu-13.10

I updated my ubuntu lately, I wanted to program in my Ubuntu 13.10, and was setting up apache2, and every time I run the command:

```
sudo a2ensite default
```

I get the following error:

> Error default site does not exist

how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To fix this and any other virtual host running on apache 2.4 I needed to set the

> default (and any other virtual host you have)

as

> default.conf (add .conf any virtual host you have already set)

Enter the console (terminal) and type the following commands:

> sudo mv /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf
>   sudo a2ensite default

And we will get the following:

```
Enabling site default. To activate the new configuration, I needed to run: service apache2 reload
```

now run:

```
service apache2 reload
```

and done.

or create the default.conf file if you don't have it and this is what it should contain by default:

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way of doing it is adding your .conf file or your virtual host configurations to the ***site-available*** folder and then when in the folder and then try again. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I tried changing my virtual host configuration file name from `default` to `default.conf`, as mentioned here, and it was still not working.

At last i got it. It is necessary also to change the code:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

to

```
Require all granted
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

After that, I've restarted apache and it worked again